# Error 'App' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am creating a simple form with react.js and getting this error:

> :- Line 5:18: 'App' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

My `app.js` file:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return ( )
    }
}

export default App
```

Comment: The `render` method of a react component should return a JSX element. As you have it written, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: return <div>Some JSX</div>;

Comment: import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Table from './Table'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Table />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App

Answer (score 1):

Check this line in the file `index.js` :

```
import App from './App';
```

**Solution 1 :**
The first letter of `App` must be uppercased like `import App from..` not `import app from..`

**Solution 2 :**
Otherwise if your file is named like `app.js`, rename it to `App.js`

Answer (score 0):

Don't leave your `return()` empty. Try this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'; 
import Table from './Table';

class App extends Component { 
render() { 
return (
<div>
//enter any jsx in here
</div>
) 
} 
}

export default App;
```

Comment: class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Table />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

Comment: this is what iam doing and still not getting the result

Comment: The error is most probably in `index.js`, then.
You need to check where you're importing it.
Check that there is `import App from './app.js';` at the top.
Make sure the your `app.js` file and the `from  './app.js'` have the same case.